# Is there any way to restrict API methods in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, api

I refer:http://vinaikopp.com/2017/02/18/magento2_repositories_interfaces_and_webapi/
So apart from that any other way possible to restrict API and also is it possible to restrict few methods in API which is provided by Magento2?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: create a resource which is allocated to no one. Add this resource to API which you want to restrict.